# SharePoint Workflow - Reminder by date/time

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I am trying to create a workflow which will send a reminder email to the user if the item has not been return by the expected return date/time (time is also required).  Here is the image for the loop.  I can't get this to work properly.  I want the loop to **immediately** terminate if the status is changed to 'returned', but when I changed the status to return it seem that it is in the pause state before it goes up to check the status?

Any ideas what's wrong here?  Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve using parallel block. Here is my workflow how that sends reminders and also check the request is approved.

[image]

**Important**

To exit the parallel block if one of the steps completes. You have to set the "Parallel block" properties.

I have created a workflow variable "Exec any one Parallel Step" set to "Yes"

Now set this property to parallel block.

[image]

[image]

This flow sends daily reminders and wait for the status change. If status changes to "Approve" then workflow completes.

You can change the "Send Reminder" logic same as yours.

Comment: Thanks this worked.  It is really strange the way loop is designed here.  One would expect the loop to terminate regardless of its current state!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the issue with this approach is that when you are storing [Today] in your variable, It is simply taking values for that particular day only when WF is started. It is not changing dynamically.I assume, Since you are running the WF once only say on ItemCreated hence your condition (Expected return date <= today) always meets.

Solution: I would suggest you can perform calculations on Return Date and then use "Pause Until" Activity in your SPD Workflow. Please refer SS and modify your workflow accordingly.[image]

Comment: Thanks I will try this shortly. I want to send the reminder after the return time has passed? Your solution will continue to work even if there is no update/change made to the WF? What I means is it would continously check if deadline has passed (it is time also not just days) rather than on change.

Comment: yes, sure. Do let me know

Comment: The problem with this would be it will send the workflow after the reminder has been sent.  I want this to continue until the status has changed to return.  I want to send reminder every few hours until status is returned.  Hence I think Loop is necessary?

Comment: I have now fully tested without loop you can't achieve.  So my original approach is correct but I can't get this to immediately break from the loop?