# Custom workflow with 1 month reminder, 2 week reminder and daily reminder emails?

Tags: workflow, email, reminder

I am having trouble creating a workflow that sends out a reminder email a month before the review date, 2 weeks before the review date and then daily reminders once it passes the review date. Have attached an image of the workflow I have created so far.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of action and flow you need for your requirements. You may need to adjust according to your business case.

[image]

Comment: I am trying to achieve something similar and I posted a question earlier here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218169/sharepoint-workflow-reminder-by-date-time.  I wonder if loop will terminate when the status changed?  I noticed that loop doesn't immediately terminate.

Comment: Yes. In the loop we can set the boolean variable when status changes which helps to terminate the loop.

Comment: I thought so but it doesn't really get terminated. It stays in the loop until the pause time has passed. Please can you look at my question?  Thanks

Comment: You can add a parallel block where one step sends reminders and another step wait for status change. If either of the steps completes parallel block completes execution.

Comment: So loop doesn't get terminated on condition unless you have a parallel block?

Comment: Yes. Without parallel block, it will still pause even though status changes.