# Pause for duration - problem

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, pause

Workflow doesn't resume after a **pause**.

I have 2 list workflows which are used to send reminder emails. Workflows work in the loop and in one of them I use 'Pause for Duration 1 minute'.

To check if it is working I added six items. Five of them are working fine however one workflow didn't unpause. It is already paused about 20 hours. What caused this issue? What should I do to avoid this situation?

Comment: Is there any screen shot for workflow rules?

Comment: Have a look at this... you might need parallel process: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218169/sharepoint-workflow-reminder-by-date-time